# best api approach for magento interaction in android native app

Tags: magento-1.9, api, web-services, android

I am working on android app which is linked with magento website.I tried to to use soap api for fetching data into android app but this api is too much slow as expecting.
So, How to interact with magento website for fetching data in android app any best approach.
Can I use the various magento model functions and fetch data from it.
Please let me know asap.